# Add a JQuery Effect to a Plain JS Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am quite new at JQuery (in fact, new to JS too) and I am trying to add a fade in effect to a JS function wich I wrote to change images in a photo gallery when the "thumbnail" of another image is selected. Code is:

```
//For HTML - the "thumbs" area:

<img id="g1" class="thg" onclick="trocafoto(this.id)"     src="fotos/sopa.jpg">
<img id="g2"class="thg" onclick="trocafoto(this.id)" src="fotos/salmao.jpg">//and so on

//The place where pictures are displayed:

<img  class="portif" id="alvo" src="fotos/sopa.jpg">

//The JS Function itself: 

function trocafoto(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id).src ;
    document.getElementById("alvo").src = x;
    }
```

I'd like to add a JQuery Fade Out effect for the previous image displayed, and the Fade In for the last selected image once the funcion is fired. But I am not finding a way to mix the JQuery Code with the plain JS... How could I call only the JQuery function without need to target it to the same element again?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var $alvo = $('#alvo');
$('.thg').on('click', function(){
  var clickedImgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
  // first hide alvo
  $alvo.fadeOut( "slow", function() {
      // fadeOut Animation is complete.
      // Add the new src to alvo and fadeIn
      $(this).attr('src', clickedImgSrc).fadeIn();
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="g1" class="thg" src="fotos/sopa.jpg">
<img id="g2" class="thg" src="fotos/salmao.jpg">

<img  class="portif" id="alvo" src="fotos/sopa.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works : ) I need to understand better the syntax you used for nesting the functions and some other details. Tips about where to get more details online about these fundaments would be appreciated. for example, $(this).attr( 'src',clickedImgSrc).fadeIn();   .   Thanks once again.

Comment: @RodrigoCastro You are welcome! Just google for things you think you don't understand, try to stick with the official documentations in this case http://jquery.com/ if something doesn't work, try, try and try and then ask on stackoverflow, someone will help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
document.getElementById("alvo")
```

You can reach an element using

```
$("#alvo")
```

So in your case

```
$("#alvo").fadeOut();
```

would work for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **thumbnails** than probably you do have **higher resolution images** too.
That's good for faster page loading! So in that case store the higher quality  image path inside a `data-*` attribute like:

```js
var $alvo = $("#alvo"); // The larger target image

$(".thg").on("click", function(){
  // First, make sure the HQ image is loaded from the server
  var img = new Image();
  $(img).on("load", function(){
      // Than assign it to #alvo
      $alvo.hide().prop("src", img.src).fadeIn();
  });
  // getting the path from data attribute of the clicked thumbnail
  img.src = this.dataset.hq;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="thg" src="//placehold.it/60x60/cf5" data-hq="//placehold.it/400x200/cf5">
<img class="thg" src="//placehold.it/60x60/f5c" data-hq="//placehold.it/400x200/f5c">
<br>
<img id="alvo" src="//placehold.it/400x200/cf5">
```

If you don't want the loading image delay than you could preload in a loop all the HQ images, but that defies the purpose of faster page load. A remedy could be adding a loading spinner when a thumbnail is clicked.